# Multiple Haproxy running on openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, haproxy, nodebb

I am hosting my nodebb forum on openshift free host with scaling enabled. I had cloudflare. I recently changed the nameserver to godaddy default without stopping the openshift app. Now I am getting a 503 service unavaliable. I took a look into the log:

```
proxy `express` has no server availiable.
```

I tried to port forward the app and i got this:

```
Service Local                OpenShift
```

---

```
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8080   =>  127.7.102.2:8080
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8081   =>  127.7.102.3:8080
mongodb 127.0.0.1:37986  =>  56cf022d0c1e6642dd000142-hackthroneht.rhcloud.com:37986
node    127.0.0.1:8082   =>  127.7.102.1:8080
```

I think its happening due to multiple haproxy running on different ports. Any solution for this?

Comment: I think you must edit your question to be more clear and specific like difficulty in code you faced while trying to migrate, etc.

Comment: @NidhinDavid Edited the question

Comment: @NidhinDavid Will it start working if i stop one haproxy?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I don know that if you hadn't edited your question, I would have been closed with 'unclear', 'too broad' ect reasons,

Comment: @NidhinDavid Ok. My real question is this. The other question was a work around for this error.

Comment: Anyone got any solution for this?